# How does Jackson deal with end-of-stream reads (e.g. -1, EOF) when parsing from underlying InputStream

Tags: java, json, stream, jackson

I have an `ObjectReader` parsing Json input from an underlying socket `InputStream` as follows:

```
jsonInput.readValue(handlerSocket.getInputStream());
```

, where `jsonInput` is the `ObjectReader` object.

I had configured `jsonInput` to parse to a particular type via the default `readFor(Class<?>)` method provided by 
the parent `ObjectMapper`. At the end of execution, part of the shutdown sequence involves shutting down the socket input i.e. calling `handlerSocket.shutdownInput()` and according to the Socket API [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) regarding `shutdownInput()`:

> Places the input stream for this socket at "end of stream". Any data sent to the input stream side of the socket is acknowledged and then silently discarded.
>   If you read from a socket input stream after invoking this method on the socket, the stream's available method will return 0, and its read methods will return -1 (end of stream).

I would have referred to the Jackson [documentation](http://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.8) regarding this particular implementation of `readValue()` but there is little to no relevant information to go on. My question is then how does Jackson treat end-of-stream type scenarios such as this one? Will `null` be returned? A parsing exception? Would appreciate your insights.

Comment: your best bet is to test the situation yourself

Comment: @Sharon Fair enough though I'd have to say it's not the most convenient option as it stands considering the current phase of development

Comment: just from experience(using it) EOF is fine. But if it cant give you what you requested, it will give you an excepton. You have a class and it tries to parse the fields of the class. If somwhere in the middle the stream  stops it complains(depending on what it was doing). Otherwise EOF itself e.g. in a REST doesn't hurt as long as it could parse what it was requested to. EG I have clases that can hold multiple objectes and REST returns only some of them: works fine. Also in case of errors: they usually throw an Exception before Jackson can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, `EOF` is normal situation when you working with streams. Problem with `EOF` will rise only when one of `JsonParser`'s notice `EOF` in "the middle" of `JSON` object. When parser will read the whole object and will be satisfied there will be no problems. Since version `2.8` `Jackson` has [`JsonEOFException`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/io/JsonEOFException.html) exception which precise when it will appear:

> Specialized JsonParseException that is thrown when end-of-input is
>   reached unexpectedly, either within token being decoded, or during
>   skipping of intervening white-space that is not between root-level
>   tokens (that is, is within JSON Object or JSON Array construct).

It is used in internal `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase` parser class which is extended by many specific parsers such as `UTF8StreamJsonParser`. One from many methods which is used to handle `EOF`:

```
    protected void _reportInvalidEOF(String msg, JsonToken currToken) throws JsonParseException {
        throw new JsonEOFException(this, currToken, "Unexpected end-of-input"+msg);
    }
```

Comment: Enlightening answer. Now given the parser is not in the middle of parsing any Json object at the moment  (i.e. in this case the underlying `handlerSocket` stream  is blocking on read); what would be the **specific** behaviour of the parser when the first token is an EOF message? What will it return?

Comment: If `parser is not in the middle of parsing any Json object at the moment` then when we start parsing new object using `readValue` method will receive `JsonEOFException` because `START_OF_*` token was expected.

Comment: Also for more info take a look on this method and its documentation: https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory.html#createParser(java.io.InputStream)

Comment: Will go at it. Are you part of the Jackson dev team, just out of curiosity?

Comment: No, I made only one small fix to `Jackson`. But I am using it in daily basis so I know a little about it and love to help other devs.

Comment: Appreciate the spirit, and Jackson is a great library